# Given two numbers a, b transcendent and algebraically dependent and c one number, if a, b and c are algebraically dependent, then c is transcendent

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Given two numbers a, b transcendent and algebraically dependent and c one number, if a, b and c are algebraically dependent, then c is transcendent. Is this result true? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Have you studied the trascendence degree of an extension?

Comment: No, i dont study  the trascendence degree of an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Indeed, take $(a,b,c)=(\pi,2\pi,0)$. Then $2a−b=c$, however $c$ is not transcendental.